# Italics/emphasized text not working after a mathematical formula

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, formatting

In this post over here: [Convergence of Series of Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11294/convergence-of-series-of-functions/11295#11295) i have noticed an error. When i put * a * the text doesn't turn italic, but its remaining the same. Not sure whats problem.

Comment: Crazily enough, it italicizes in the preview, but doesn't when posted as an answer.

Comment: @J.M: Yes! Don't really know whats wrong.

Comment: After an $\mathbb R$ *I wonder* what happens...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clearly a bug. In the meantime, add **two** spaces after the `$` to workaround.

> ```
> Well, to see that $f(x)$  *converges uniformly* please...
>                         ^^
> ```
>
> Well, to see that $f(x)$  *converges uniformly* please ...

Answer (score 6):

I'll try *putting this one* and then *putting this one* in italic, to see what happens.

Heck, I'll try **doing this** and then **this again** in bold.

So both of those work, but if

I try putting something like $\sqrt{x}$ *before this one* and then *this one* in here, or

I try something like $\frac12$ **before doing this** and then **this again**, let's see what happens.

Comment: i.e., somebody's regexes are screwy... :P

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed on dev, and will go out sometime in the near future (probably 6+ hours from now).

Will only affect new and edited posts, naturally.